# List contents of varnish cache

Tags: varnish

Is there a way to list the contents of the varnish cache storage? Also, it would be nice to somehow list the most frequent cache hits.

I found a way to see the most frequent cache misses by listing what is being sent to the backend with:

```
varnishtop -b -i TxURL
```

It would be very useful to see what are my top cache hits URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer was originally posted on stackoverflow, and I think it is quite helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214104/list-contents-of-varnish-cache

You can use the parameter "Varnish:hitmiss" of varnishncsa.

First capture a sample of logs with:

`varnishncsa -F '%U%q %{Varnish:hitmiss}x' -n NAME -w /path/requests.logs`

and then:

`sort -k 1 /path/requests.logs | uniq -c | sort -k 1 -n -r | head -25`

Comment: Soemthing is wrong with this answer. THis command gives me `varnishncsa: invalid option -- 'F'`

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of listing the contents of the cache.

You can get the list of top requested URLs with

```
varnishtop -i RxURL
```

but there's no easy way to tell from that which are cache HITs and MISSes. There is a script [here](http://www.dmsp.de/varnish-cache-scripts-and-helpers-in-perl-and-bash-for-debugging-and-bug-hunting) which may help you.

Comment: actually posted the same question on stackoverflow, got some info from there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214104/list-contents-of-varnish-cache